# Add new rows based on values in columns in Excel

Tags: excel, powerquery

I have an Excel table with thousands of rows which looks like this:

```
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|      COUNTRY        |       DATE       |      ITEM 1      |     ITEM 2       |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|       Ireland       |     Jan-1        |       40         |       56         |    
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

What I need to make it look like is below:

```
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|      COUNTRY        |       DATE       |      COUNT       |       ITEM       |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|       Ireland       |     Jan-1        |       40         |      ITEM 1      |    
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|       Ireland       |     Jan-1        |       56         |      ITEM 2      |    
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

Can you please suggest the way how to do this? I'm open to both non-VBA and VBA solutions.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you thought of pivot table?

Comment: Could you suggest how that pivot table should be done? I tried but didn't get the desired result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Powerquery add-in 2013, data tab > Get and Transform Excel 2016

Select cell in range > data tab (or powerquery tab) > data from table > select columns Item 1 and Item 2 > right click > unpivot > Rename attribute column as Item and Value as Count by double clicking on headers.Re-order columns as required by drag and drop. Home tab > Close and Load to new sheet

M code:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"COUNTRY        ", type text}, {"       DATE       ", type date}, {"      ITEM 1      ", Int64.Type}, {"     ITEM 2       ", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Unpivoted Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Changed Type", {"COUNTRY        ", "       DATE       "}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Unpivoted Columns",{{"Value", "Count"}, {"Attribute", "Item"}}),
    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Renamed Columns",{"COUNTRY        ", "       DATE       ", "Count", "Item"})
in
    #"Reordered Columns"
```

Result:

[image: Result]